# how to add pandas columns as key value pairs to existing python dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have an existing dictionary, and I would like to append values from a pandas dataframe; one column would be the keys, and the other column would be the values.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

# existing dictionary
mydict = {'hello': 42}

# a pandas dataframe;
d = {'name': ['a', 'b'], 'val': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# update dict with df colums
mydict.update(zip(df.name.tolist(), df.val.tolist()))
```